# How to convert strings to bytes in a for in python

Tags: python

I have a List of strings, but when I try to count the elements in the List which match a string, I get a byte error.  Here's the code:

```
def countTransactions(data, lineDelim, marker):
  lines = data.split(lineDelim)
  return len([i for i in lines if marker in i])
```

And here's the error I see:

```
  File "//./main.py", line 328, in <module>
    topTransactions = countTransactions(topString, bin_delimiter, TMARKER)
  File "//./main.py", line 188, in countTransactions
    return len([i for i in lines if marker in i])
  File "//./main.py", line 188, in <listcomp>
    return len([i for i in lines if marker in i])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

If my List is indeed a List of bytes not strings, how do I fix this?

Comment: `bytes` have the `encode` method to convert them to a string if you know the used encoding ("UTF-8" by default).

Comment: Print the types out and add that information to your question

Comment: What's the relationship between these bytes and strings? There is no inherent comparison between these two things. Lets say that the bytes objects are encoded strings. Then you could decode them. Lets say they are jpeg images ... then they wouldn't be comparable. You need to tell us how these are related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your data variable might be of bytes type rather than a string. You can decode it to a string before splitting it into lines. you can modify your function

```
def countTransactions(data, lineDelim, marker):
    # Decode data if it's of bytes type
    if isinstance(data, bytes):
        data = data.decode()
    
    lines = data.split(lineDelim)
    return len([i for i in lines if marker in i])
```

Comment: suppose I receive the data as a file (like an object in an S3 bucket), should I decode() it at first, then deal with it as bytes throughout the program, then re-encode it back to bytes?  It seems like the line data.decode() is changing the data here, should I change it back?  I know in this function I am ust counting, but in other places I might be manipulating data.